# Raise PropertyChanged on custom properties in EntityObject

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, inotifypropertychanged

I have several custom calculated properties on an EntityObject. I would like to fire the PropertyChanged event to notify all bindings. This does not work however, and it throws an argumentexception when I use ReportPropertyChanged:

> De eigenschap Name heeft geen geldige
>   entiteitstoewijzing op het
>   entiteitsobject. Zie de documentatie
>   van Entity Framework voor meer
>   informatie.

Which means than `Name` is not an entity property and I should look in the Entity Framework documentation for more information. Is there any way to call the event and have the Entity Framework ignore it?

code example:

```
partial class Preset
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.SystemPreset)
                return Translate("preset_" + this.Name_Original + "_name");
            else
                return this.Name_Original;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!value != this.Name_Internal)
            {
                this.Name_Internal = value;
                ReportPropertyChanged(Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The property Name is a custom property. The entity framework will throw an exception when I try to fire PropertyChanged through the method ReportPropertyChanged in EntityObject.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Code for a property that isn't working, for instance.  And "ReportPropertyChanged" - where is that?

Comment: ReportPropertyChanged is a method in EntityObject which fires the PropertyChanged event. The problem is that the Entity Framework listens in on this PropertyChanged event and fires an ArgumentException on unknown properties.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just call `OnPropertyChanged("YourPropertyName")` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338418.aspx)) from your custom property setter and WPF will pick it up.

This works for me in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0 talking to an SQLServer CE database (I think it's entity framework 4 but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

*ReportPropertyChanged* is not for your use it's for the EF to notify *ObjectStateManager* to change the *CurrentValues* for that object so that it can keep track of the changes and generate appropriate SQL commands at later point when we call *SaveChanges* on *ObjectContext*. 

That said, every scalar property of every entity has its own version of 2 partial methods that is there for you to implement: ***On[Property]Changed*** and ***On[Property]Changing***.

There is no default implementation for PropertyChanging and PropertyChanged; only a declaration. This provides you the opportunity to execute custom logic as the property is about to change (PropertyChanging) as well as just after the property value has changed (PropertyChanged) and you can use them to update the value of your custom calculated properties.

Comment: What I want is to be able to fire the PropertyChanged event for custom properties which I have added in the partial class, not act on changes of properties generated by the Entity Framework..

Comment: Then you don't need any special method or event for your that, you can do what you need to do in the setter method of your custom property. EF is not aware of your custom properties, therefore, there is no out of the box API that you can use for this. What is your exact scenario?

Comment: The problem is not calling the event, the problem is that Entity Framework throws an exception because it is also listening in on PropertyChanged events of my custom properties.

Comment: Now that I see your code, you need to absolutely remove `ReportPropertyChanged(Name);` from the setter of *Name* property, you don't need that in your custom property and you should not call it.

Comment: I do, because there is no other way of calling the PropertyChanged event implemented in the EntityObject class.